# How to increase minimum iOS version for iPhone app installation?

Tags: ios, app-store

I recently submitted a new version of my app to the app store, and increased the Deployment Target to 3.2, to make the app no longer able to install on iOS 3.1.3 which is not compatible with it. However, when the app went live on the store, it still is listed as "Compatible with iOS 3.1.3 or later." How can I increase the minimum iOS version for the App Store, so that users with older iOS versions won't be able to install the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to empty the "build" folder inside of your project folder and test the app either on the device or in the simulator once before resubmitting it for review.